null value that should not exist
little by little but right now I have this error "Attempt to read property "name" on null" and in my database I have the information so that it has to appear in my view, please help my database data is full and my cities and countries are all well organized and it still gives me the error when calling a data from the cities_id source table
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\app.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tittle">
        <h1>hola</h1>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">id</th>
                <th scope="col">nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">correo</th>
                <th scope="col">ciudad</th>
                <th scope="col">pais</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->city->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->city && $user->city->country ? $user->city->country->name : 'N/A'}}</td>
            </tr> 
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

the view
the models
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Country;

class City extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(country::class);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\City;

class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(city::class);
    }
}

?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use App\Models\City;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function city(){
        return $this->belongsTo(city::class);
    }
}


You're not handling null chaining correctly. You've got this:
{{ $user->city && $user->city->country ? $user->city->country->name : 'N/A' }}

Which is OK, but then right above it, you have this:
{{ $user->city->name }}

with no checks... If any User's City is null, then null->name will trigger, which is not valid.
Since you've got this tagged as laravel-10, which I believe requires PHP 8, you can use the ?-> operator:
{{ $user?->city?->name ?? 'N/A' }}
{{ $user?->city?->country?->name ?? 'N/A' }}

If you can't use that operator, then you need to chain it:
{{ $user->city ? $user->city->name : 'N/A' }}
{{ $user->city && $user->city->country ? $user->city->country->name : 'N/A' }}


I tried but I need it to show me the names of the city and the country and they are associated with one. It seems strange to me that it doesn't give me what I ask for.
same thanks

I'm not sure what you're saying there... This code will fix your error "Attempting to access property "name" on null". If you're not getting the results you expect, that's a separate issue, and you'll need to check your database to see why.
